# Maven profiles - shared goals across profiles

Tags: maven

Is it possible to have certain goals shared across profiles? I have a multiplatform POM which should do the following:

- Windows? Do thing A.
- Mac or Linux? Do thing B, AND

  - Mac? Set property XYZ to value 1.
  - Linux x86? Set property XYZ to value 2.
  - Linux x64? Set property XYZ to value 3.

It would be possible to have four different profiles and that would work, however, everything except setting property XYZ would be duplicated three times in the POM. Can I get rid of that?

Comment: What exactly needed to be done for the different platforms?

Comment: I'm doing some non-java tasks in there (via exec).

Comment: You would like that someone will help? Than you should offer more information on what you like to do.